# Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.actions.ItemListIntents

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to set up the Google GMS Licenses to show up the licenses of used libraries in my app after following [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/opensource) from the google website i'm getting the following error when trying to run the app

```
Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.actions.ItemListIntents
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.actions.ItemListIntents, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

How can i fix an error like that?

Answer (score 0):

It means you already have google-play-services lib in your project... that may be in some of the modules or dependencies in the project.

Remove one of them and the error will go away.